# PayFlow Pro - Use a Recurring Billing Profile ID to get a history of Transactions

Tags: paypal, history, recurring-billing, payflowpro

I am using PayFlow Pro Payments for Recurring Billing.

I want to be able to use the API to be able to grab the transaction history for a particular Recurring Profile ID - however the API is not clear enough.

I have been reading up on the TRXTYPE=I - But I can't get the transaction ID as PayFlow is the one that does the recurring billing. I can create/update/cancel subscriptions just fine - but I can't get any transaction history out of it at all. I can browse online for them by going through Manage Profiles, Selecting a profile and then clicking on "View Transactions"

So if I do a call like this

`VENDOR[9]=*********&PARTNER[3]=***&USER[9]=*********&PWD[11]=***********&TRXTYPE[1]=I&CUSTREF[12]=RP0000000158`

I get back

"CUSTREF invalid "

If I do

`VENDOR[9]=*********&PARTNER[3]=***&USER[9]=*********&PWD[11]=***********&TRXTYPE[1]=I&ORIGID[12]=RP0000000158`

I get back

"Not signed up for this Tender type"

If I throw in the Tender type Tender[1]=C or Tender[1]=P; still the same issue.

If I chuck in one of the transaction ID's MANUALLY then I get details of the transaction - but I want to grab a list of transactions done for a recurring profile :(

Any advice/direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Page 30 of the Payflow Recurring Payments Developer Guide it details the parameters for running an inquiry on a recurring payment. Below in the information:

**TRXTYPE** Specifies a recurring profile request. Must be **“R”** 
**ACTION** Specifies action to take. Must be “I” 
**ORIGPROFILEID** Profile ID of the profile to inquire about.
Profile IDs for test profiles start with **RT**. Profile IDs for live profiles start with RP.

Just in case you need it here is the Payflow Recurring Payments Developer Guide:

[Payflow Recurring Payments Developer Guide](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_payflowpro_recurringbilling_guide.pdf)

Comment: OH MAN. The documentation I was given to consult was this one - https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/payflowgateway_guide.pdf ; it doesn't have that information. Thank you soo much. That is such an easy solution.

Comment: Got it easy, had to chuck in PAYMENTHISTORY=Y. Ah, life is good again.